# Convert numeric (contains special characters) to money

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Given

```
declare @text varchar(4) ='3677.98*' , @text2 varchar(4) ='1245367.98%'
```

I want the output as follows:

**3,677.98* and 1,245,367.98%**

I tried below:

```
select convert(varchar,cast(3677.98 as money),1) --output as 3,677.98
```

If I try `select convert(varchar,cast(3677.98* as money),1)` it gives the error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: 3677.98* is not a valid money representation; thus the error message.

Comment: You're going to have to "wash" the data. Either do it permanently by updating all the rows in the offending table, to get rid of things that will prevent type conversion, or do it as part of your type conversion every time.

Comment: Do you have data with many decimal places?  Will you want group separators there, too?  E.g. should 12.3456% show as 12.345,6% ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a varchar to Money format, the only currency symbols it can use are in [this chart, from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx). * and % do not qualify.

If you want to store the number amount and the special character, you will need to either store them as a varchar or use two columns, a money and a varchar.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a UDF which identifies the decimal separator and works out from there, adding commas (or locale-appropriate equivalent) to the output as it goes.  This won't be great for your query elapsed times, however.